# php: DateTime within WP loop

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime

I'm using a DateTime function within a WP loop, attaching a range of dates to each post (start date to end date) which can then be filtered out using a jQuery calendar. The only problem is, each post is being given the same dates, all the posts are taking the dates of the first post, instead of having their own individual dates.
PHP:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'title01' ),
    'order' => 'asc',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<div class="grid-block-calendar" data-value="<?php $newBegin = DateTime::createFromFormat('dnY', get_field('title01_date_select'));
$newEnd = DateTime::createFromFormat('dnY', get_field('exhibition_date_end'));
$newEnd = $newEnd->modify( '+1 day' );

$newDaterange = new DatePeriod($newBegin, new DateInterval('P1D'), $newEnd);

foreach($newDaterange as $newDate){
    echo $newDate->format("jnY") . " ";
} ?>">
</div>
</a>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'title02' ),
    'order' => 'asc',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<div class="grid-block-calendar" data-value="<?php $begin = DateTime::createFromFormat('dnY', get_field('title02_date_select'));
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('dnY', get_field('title02_date_end'));
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' );

$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo $date->format("jnY") . " ";
} ?>">
</div>
</a>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

e.g. The first post displays a date range between 15/05/2013 and 09/09/2013, and instead of this being the date range for only the first post, it's being shown in the `data-value` for all the posts, but each individual post has separate start dates and end dates.
Is there a reason all my posts are taking the same date? I know it's probably something simple, but I can't figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem most likely is the: `get_field('title02_date_end')`
If you var_dump it what is inside?

I would advise to use it like this: `get_field('title02_date_end', get_the_ID())`
See if var_dumping that gives something else.

Comment: yes, i ran `var_dump(get_field('title02_date_select'));` which successfully show the start date for each post (each one being different), and `var_dump(get_field('title02_date_end'));` which again successfully shows the end date for each posts (each one being different). So I'm at a loss as to why each post is taking the same date range?

Comment: I wouldn't know, but I think the problem is the datetime. I would recommand var_dumping every step to narrow it down where it goes wrong. So every thing you do set it in a variable. and dump that. No function nesting.

Comment: yeah, it's a confusing one, cheers for your suggestion though, much appreciated! I've been running more test, and it actually isn't the datetime (I thought it was too). As I've took out both datetime functions and replaced them with regular text fields, but still, they're all showing the same. It's something to do with the loop, but it's odd as the rest of the fields within the loop are working fine...

Comment: do other fields use `get_field()` you could try `get_post_meta()` wild guess.....

Comment: turns out it wasn't a php problem, I've found the root of the problem, but I've not found a fix for it yet. Turns out it's on the jQuery, in this fiddle (because it's too long): http://jsfiddle.net/dsXxq/ so the `data-value` all being the same is caused by the `~=` in the jQuery, removing the `~` brought the dates back, but now the datepicker function doesn't work :( a bit odd.